# What is the correct way to log information in a Grails JUnit test case?

Tags: grails, junit, intellij-idea, log4j, slf4j

I have recently started using Grails for a project.
I am working from the Intellij Idea environment.

I am writing unit test in order to test the services I create.

I am unable to log information from the test cases. No matter the log level I use there is no message displayed in the console.

Here is my log4j configuration in Config.groovy:

```
log4j = {
    appenders {
        console name: 'stdout', layout: pattern(conversionPattern: '%d{yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss} [%t] %-5p %c{1}:%L %x - %m%n')
    }

    root {
        info    'a1'
        additivity = true
    }

    error  'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.servlet',        // controllers
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.pages',          // GSP
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.sitemesh',       // layouts
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping.filter', // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.mapping',        // URL mapping
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons',            // core / classloading
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins',            // plugins
           'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.orm.hibernate',      // hibernate integration'org.springframework',
           'org.springframework',
           'org.hibernate',
           'org.apache',
           'net.sf.ehcache.hibernate'

    debug  'grails.app.controllers'
           'hibernate.SQL'
            'grails.app'
}
```

I also have to mention the fact that when I run the test case I get the following messasge at the beginning but from what I have read it is just a warning and it should not influence the test case.

```
SLF4J: Class path contains multiple SLF4J bindings.
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/E:/abujdei/grails/grails-2.3.7/dist/grails-plugin-log4j-2.3.7.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: Found binding in [jar:file:/E:/abujdei/grails/grails-2.3.7/lib/org.slf4j/slf4j-simple/jars/slf4j-simple-1.7.5.jar!/org/slf4j/impl/StaticLoggerBinder.class]
SLF4J: See http:/www.slf4j.org/codes.html#multiple_bindings for an explanation.
SLF4J: Actual binding is of type [org.slf4j.impl.GrailsSlf4jLoggerFactory]
log4j:WARN No appenders could be found for logger (org.springframework.core.env.StandardEnvironment).
log4j:WARN Please initialize the log4j system properly.
log4j:WARN See http:/logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/faq.html#noconfig for more info.
```

I have been struggling with this for a couple od hours now.

Answer (score 2):

In Intellij's Grails View, when you rightclick a testable node (package, class or method), under *Run* you should have two options:

- using junit runner (standard test icon, not aware of your grails configuration)
- using grails test-app command (grails icon, I think you want to use this one.)

Note that if your version of grails uses forked test execution by default, you have to either ([source](http://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2014/02/grails-goodness-run-forked-tests-in.html)):

- disable it: `grails.project.fork.test = false` in grails-app/conf/BuildConfig.groovy
- copy `<Intellij_install_dir>/plugins/Grails/grails-rt.jar` to your project's lib.

Comment: I must test and I will get back to you.

Answer (score 0):

You should reference the console appender in the root-block:

```
// ...
root {
  info 'stdout'
  additivity = true
}
// ...
```

I've put an example for logging in different environments at [snipplr](http://snipplr.com/view/63391/grails-log4j-for-different-environments--an-example/), not using the console appender, but it might still be useful.

Comment: And are you sure that this works in the junit test ? Because I am still unable to figure this out.